# Add private/hidden fields/data to Careers profile

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

I'd like to add "private data" to my Stack Overflow resume that only I can see. For example, "past salaries", "contact names", etc. This will allow me to reference this information when looking for/applying to jobs, but not be visible to recruiters, companies, etc.

Comment: a passport photo and favorite meal too?

Comment: This *sounds* like it might be useful, but if you really want to keep this information private, do you really think the best thing to do would be to give it out on the Internet? Why don't you just track this yourself, in your personal files?

Comment: Maybe I'm in the minority @Cody, but I store a lot of private information on web servers that I don't own because I trust the technical ability and morals of the providers, e.g. tax preparation,  banking sites, google docs. Are you saying that Careers is inherintly less trustworthy, or that storing any private information on the web is bad, or something else?

Comment: @jball I'm saying, why should they store this information if they aren't doing anything useful with it? Presumably you're storing that information on other sites because they use it to provide you with related information and/or services. You trust them, because the benefits outweigh the risks. He's simply asking that Careers track this information so that it will be tracked. He doesn't want them to use it for statistical reasons, or to automatically send it to potential employers. I see little point, therefore, in them maintaining it. It is not a backup service.

Comment: @Cody, that makes sense to me, though it does seem entirely different than your first comment. As a counterpoint, google docs is allegedly not doing anything on their end with the information I give them. The question of what Careers gains from it is a fair point. Usability may be reason enough though if it would really aid a significant number of users, though that's in the realm of speculation for me.

Comment: Careers /could/ use the data in the future for filtering job suggestions. How I see this as being beneficial: When I'm sending my CV to people, I might not want them to know the previous salaries: but I may want to know myself that X years ago in Y area, I was earning Z. Yes, I could keep it in a separate location: but then I may as well keep my CV/resume separate as well...

Answer (score 3):

Some of these suggestions have merit, and your comment about how we could use the data for future filtering job suggestions is a good one.

While marked as declined, I do think there will be some movement on our side around the salary issue for both employers and candidates to help with matching.  Private data of that nature could help our core product.

Information like contact names, previous applications etc... are not a profile feature but should be easier to maintain in our messaging interface.